# Passing an array between pages in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, arrays, typescript, ionic2

I'm new in Ionic 2 and I'm having troubles with passing data between pages. In my Home.ts file  I have a global array that contains some numbers I calculated and i want to pass it to my Table.ts file, to show it in a HTML table with the *ngFor method.

this is the Function in Home.ts where i fill the array and try to push (i will skip the calculations, becacause i know they are correct).

```
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { IonicPage,NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
 import {Table} from '../table/table';

 export class HomePage {

 averagesList: Array <number> =[];

 constructor(public alerCtrl: AlertController,
             public navCtrl: NavController,
             public navParams: NavParams)
             {}

 Calculate(){

 var Averages=[];

 //Calculations on the 'Averages' Array

 this.averagesList = Averages;


this.navCtrl.push(Table,this.averagesList);
 }

}
```

So I try to print it in my Table.ts file but it gives me undefined result

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-table',
templateUrl: 'table.html',
})
export class Table{


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

}

ionViewDidLoad() {

console.log(this.navParams.get('averagesList'));
}
}
```

I've tried to pass a let variable and it worked, so why doesn't it work with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is using `console.log(this.navParams.get('averagesList'));`

Here 'averagesList' is the key.

To get it this way, you need to send as :

```
this.navCtrl.push(Table,{'averagesList' : this.averagesList});
```

Else:

if you directly send as

```
this.navCtrl.push(Table,this.averagesList);
```

You can retrieve value like so:

```
console.log(this.navParams.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use services to do so. Just like in angular2 you can import your service within the constructor and use the property like this.

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {someService} from ./somepath;
 ...
 export class someClass implements OnInit{
let myTmpVar; //we will capture the shared data in this variable
constructor (private smService: someService){ ... }
ngOnInit{ 
   this.myTmpVar = this.smService.SharedServiceData;
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use service for passing nested data. In your case calculations object.

You can create messageService and listen to changes, something like below.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

 export class LocalMsgService {  

private subject = new Subject();

sendMessage(message) {
    this.subject.next(message);
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
}

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
     return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Which can be used in your home.ts and table.ts pages as follows

Home.ts

```
    //other imports comes here 
    import {LocalMsgService} from 'services/localMsg';


    @Component({
        selector: 'home-component',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
        constructor( private msgService: LocalMsgService) {

          }

        dataToPass() {
            console.log(this.averagesList);
            this.msgService.sendMessage(this.averagesList);
        }

    }
```

Table.ts

```
       //other imports comes here 
       import {LocalMsgService} from 'services/localMsg';
       import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';


        @Component({
           selector: 'page-table',
          templateUrl: 'table.html',
        })

        export class TablePage{

            items: any;
            subscription: Subscription;

            constructor(
            public localMsgService : LocalMsgService) {
                this.subscription = this.localMsgService.getMessage().subscribe(msg => {
                    this.items = msg;
                });
            }

        }
```